# why dose it print after the loop while it was written in a loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

```
int main(){
    int m, k, a, b;
    scanf_s("%d%d%d", &n, &m, &k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        fill(visit, visit + 1010, false);
        scanf_s("%d", &a);
        int cnt = 0;
        visit[a] = true;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            if (visit[j] == false){
                dfs(j);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", cnt - 1); 
  }
    return 0;
}
```

*why will it print after all numbers are scaned instead of print {cnt-1} every time when I give it a integer*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because scanf_s("%d",&a) recoginize an "Enter"key as the end of the input.if we  input an integer and an Enter it will show results at once however if we use space to seperate the inputs and press "Enter" at last. the integers will be processed one by one.